# Ruby on Rails redirect to www. only if no subdomain is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I'm trying to redirect to www. only if another subdomain is not present.

If the url is `example.com` then I want to redirect to `www.example.com`

If the url is `blog.example.com` then I don't want to redirect.

I have tried this but it add www. to every url even if another subdomain is already present.

```
constraints(host: /^(?!www\.)/i) do
  get '' => redirect { |params, request|
    URI.parse(request.url).tap { |uri| uri.host = "www.#{uri.host}" }.to_s
  }
end
```

I think i need to check `subdomain.present?` somewhere but not sure where.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me. There might be a better way to go about it though.

```
  constraints(subdomain: '') do
    constraints(host: /^(?!www\.)/i) do
      get '' => redirect { |params, request|
        URI.parse(request.url).tap { |uri| uri.host = "www.#{uri.host}" }.to_s
      }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Oh yeah! completely forgot, but I have to wait two days

Answer (score 2):

I did the following in my application controller (Rails 6):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :ensure_www
  
  # Other stuff

  protected
  def ensure_www
    if request.subdomain != 'www'
      redirect_to url_for(subdomain: 'www', only_path: false)
    end
  end
end
```